# Collision using Tiled and LibGDX not working

Tags: java, libgdx, tiled

I have implemented a Player class which handles collision between the player and the objects in game. When I run it, he falls through the floor. I have followed a tutorial step by step but it is not working.

Below I have added the Player class and GameScreen class.

I have tried making rectangles around my Player to interact with, but it wasnt a fix.

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL30;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.MapObjects;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.objects.RectangleMapObject;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMap;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMapTileLayer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.renderers.OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Intersector;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.Viewport;
import inf112.skeleton.app.AGame;
import inf112.skeleton.app.entities.Player;
import inf112.skeleton.app.scenes.Hud;

public class GameScreen implements Screen {

    public AGame game;

    public TiledMap map;
    private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer mapRenderer;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    public Player player;
    private BitmapFont font;
    public Viewport gameport;
    private Hud hud;

    public GameScreen (AGame game) {
        this.game = game;
        hud = new Hud(game.batch);
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        font = new BitmapFont();
        font.setColor(Color.RED);
        font.setColor(Color.RED);

        map = new TmxMapLoader().load("assets/data/GameBoard2.tmx");

        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false, 10, 10);

        mapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map, (float)0.015625);
        mapRenderer.setView(camera);

        player = new Player((TiledMapTileLayer) map.getLayers().get("Player"));
                player.setPosition(11 * player.getCollisionLayer().getTileWidth(), (player.getCollisionLayer().getHeight() - 14) * player.getCollisionLayer().getTileHeight());


    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        mapRenderer.setView(camera);
        mapRenderer.render();

        mapRenderer.getBatch().begin();
        player.draw((SpriteBatch) mapRenderer.getBatch());
        mapRenderer.getBatch().end();

        game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(hud.stage.getCamera().combined);
        hud.stage.draw();

    }


    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        camera.viewportHeight = height;
        camera.viewportWidth = width;

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        font.dispose();
        mapRenderer.dispose();
        map.dispose();
        game.dispose();
    }
```

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMapTileLayer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;

public class Player extends Sprite implements InputProcessor {
    private String blockedKey = "blocked";

    private Vector2 velocity = new Vector2();
    private float speed = 60 * 2, gravity = 60 * 1.8f, increment;
    private boolean canJump;

    private TiledMapTileLayer collisionLayer;

    public Player(TiledMapTileLayer collisionLayer) {
        this.collisionLayer = collisionLayer;
        //setScale((float)0.1);
    }

    public void draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch) {
        update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        super.draw(spriteBatch);
    }

    public void update(float delta) {
        // apply gravity
        velocity.y -= gravity * delta;

        // clamp velocity
        if(velocity.y > speed)
            velocity.y = speed;
        else if(velocity.y < -speed)
            velocity.y = -speed;

        // save old position
        float oldX = getX(), oldY = getY();
        boolean collisionX = false, collisionY = false;

        // move on x
        setX(getX() + velocity.x * delta);

        // calculate the increment for step in #collidesLeft() and #collidesRight()
        increment = collisionLayer.getTileWidth();
        increment = getWidth() < increment ? getWidth() / 2 : increment / 2;

        if(velocity.x < 0) // going left
            collisionX = collidesLeft();
        else if(velocity.x > 0) // going right
            collisionX = collidesRight();

        // react to x collision
        if(collisionX) {
            setX(oldX);
            velocity.x = 0;
        }

        // move on y
        setY(getY() + velocity.y * delta * 5f);

        // calculate the increment for step in #collidesBottom() and #collidesTop()
        increment = collisionLayer.getTileHeight();
        increment = getHeight() < increment ? getHeight() / 2 : increment / 2;

        if(velocity.y < 0) // going down
            canJump = collisionY = collidesBottom();
        else if(velocity.y > 0) // going up
            collisionY = collidesTop();

        // react to y collision
        if(collisionY) {
            setY(oldY);
            velocity.y = 0;
        }

        // update animation
    }

    private boolean isCellBlocked(float x, float y) {
        TiledMapTileLayer.Cell cell = collisionLayer.getCell((int) (x / collisionLayer.getTileWidth()), (int) (y / collisionLayer.getTileHeight()));
        return cell != null && cell.getTile() != null && cell.getTile().getProperties().containsKey(blockedKey);
    }

    public boolean collidesRight() {
        for(float step = 0; step <= getHeight(); step += increment)
            if(isCellBlocked(getX() + getWidth(), getY() + step))
                return true;
        return false;
    }

    public boolean collidesLeft() {
        for(float step = 0; step <= getHeight(); step += increment)
            if(isCellBlocked(getX(), getY() + step))
                return true;
        return false;
    }

    public boolean collidesTop() {
        for(float step = 0; step <= getWidth(); step += increment)
            if(isCellBlocked(getX() + step, getY() + getHeight()))
                return true;
        return false;

    }

    public boolean collidesBottom() {
        for(float step = 0; step <= getWidth(); step += increment)
            if(isCellBlocked(getX() + step, getY()))
                return true;
        return false;
    }

    public Vector2 getVelocity() {
        return velocity;
    }

    public void setVelocity(Vector2 velocity) {
        this.velocity = velocity;
    }

    public float getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    public void setSpeed(float speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    public float getGravity() {
        return gravity;
    }

    public void setGravity(float gravity) {
        this.gravity = gravity;
    }

    public TiledMapTileLayer getCollisionLayer() {
        return collisionLayer;
    }

    public void setCollisionLayer(TiledMapTileLayer collisionLayer) {
        this.collisionLayer = collisionLayer;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        switch(keycode) {
            case Input.Keys.W:
                if(canJump) {
                    velocity.y = speed / 1.8f;
                    canJump = false;
                }
                break;
            case Input.Keys.A:
                velocity.x = -speed;
                break;
            case Input.Keys.D:
                velocity.x = speed;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
        switch(keycode) {
            case Input.Keys.A:
            case Input.Keys.D:
                velocity.x = 0;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(float amountX, float amountY) {
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The position of a libGDX`Sprite` is bottom left so you need to make a distinction between position as far as your render is concerned, and as far as collision is concerned.
So if you add a half tile width to the x position when checking for the collision that would match what you see, being the base of the sprite.

Imagine a tilewidth of `4f` and a position of `7f`. As you look the sprite is rendered mainly on the third tile, but the collision is tested against the second one.